# How to calculate reversible speed value while accelerating

Tags: solution-verification, education

I am working on a special video editing task and I have faced some math problem

I have video that I want to speed up for example to 200%, and to reverse (or 'cancel') it I need to do 100/200 * 100 = 50%, so this is not a problem as I get back exactly where I was, the problem if I want to accelerate from 100% to 200% over some period of time i will face values that are approximate for example speed up to 147% for the reversion I need 100/147 * 100 = 68.0272108844 (approximate), computers cannot work with approximate values and will cut some values, over time it will create a derivation, I wonder how can I avoid this

My current thought process is to pre-calculate the exact amount of the values I will receive between 100 and 200 over n time based on video fps, and leave only those values that give the exact reversible values like 100/200 * 100 = 50, and if there are not many of those then calculate the need amount of numbers that be reversed without cutting

is it possible to do?

Comment: When you speed up, are you doing it by removing frames? If you then slow it back down, are you doing it by duplicating frames? If so, then obviously, you have a very lossy process, no matter what math tricks you come up with.

Comment: If you are accelerating by changing the fps, then I suggest you remember the original fps, and for any speed changes, you calculate your new interval lengths from that original value, not the current fps. This applies more generally: when making modifications to data that you want to be reversible, keep the original data, and calculate each change from it, not the already modified data.